# T-test with confidence other than 0.95 using HypothesisTests.jl

Tags: julia, hypothesis-test

When I call the following example I receive a pretty report, but with confidence equal to 95% specifically:

```
julia> OneSampleTTest([1,2,3], 2)
One sample t-test
-----------------
Population details:
    parameter of interest:   Mean
    value under h_0:         2
    point estimate:          2.0
    95% confidence interval: (-0.48413771175033027,4.48413771175033)

Test summary:
    outcome with 95% confidence: fail to reject h_0
    two-sided p-value:           1.0 (not significant)

Details:
    number of observations:   3
    t-statistic:              0.0
    degrees of freedom:       2
    empirical standard error: 0.5773502691896258
```

I'd like to receive similar report but for confidence equal to 99%.

[The docs](http://hypothesistestsjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parametric/test_t.html#OneSampleTTest) state that `OneSampleTest` implements method [`confint`](http://hypothesistestsjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/confint.html#confint), which does receive parameter `alpha`, but it does not give me a full report as shown above.

Comment: It sounds like you probably want to submit this as an issue in the package repository, where the developers will definitely see it and be able to respond. The 95% confidence interval currently seems to be hardcoded: https://github.com/JuliaStats/HypothesisTests.jl/blob/e58291eb9edee9522842785bfc07414f1cf5a175/src/HypothesisTests.jl#L96

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Thanks, I definetely will submit this as an issue.